# Парсинг JSON в shell

Tags: json, shell, парсер

Есть JSON такого типа

```
{"response":{"upload_url":"url"}}
```

Как мне забрать url средствами только shell? В JSON.awk не разобрался,  jq не поддерживается в моем случае

Comment: А может просто костылем `grep -oP '"upload_url":"\K[^"]+'` ?

Comment: [Как на счет того чтобы воспользоваться Python, установленным в системе?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1955555/5741205)

Comment: @Mike, где прочитать про регулярки? У меня терпения не хватает их понять :(

Comment: @MaxU, я пишу скрипт в Android + Termux. Python не доступен из root.

Comment: для начала в википедии можно https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F это основы. А вот `\K` - начало захватываемого совпадения даже не знаю где описано, оно из расширения pcre, но что то даже у Лари Уолла не нашел упоминаний. http://goo.gl/XXogWS (глава 5)

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1955505

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для разбора JSON в командной строке воспользуйтесь утилитой [Jshon](http://kmkeen.com/jshon), она позволяет легко извлекать поля из объекта произвольной сложности с автоматическим раскодировыванием строк (при необходимости). Программа написана на чистом Си и из зависимостей требует только библиотеку [Jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson) (не считая стандартной **libc**).

Для вашего случая вызов будет таким:

```
echo '{"response":{"upload_url":"url"}}' | jshon -e response -e upload_url -u
```

Её можно найти в архиве Debian в одноимённом пакете.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, этот вариант лучший. Просто я им не могу воспользоваться пока :D

Answer (score 1):

```
upl=$(cut -d'"' -f6 <<<$mus)
upload_url=$(echo $upl | tr -d '\')
```

Работает

Answer (score 0):

Есть классная **fx** https://github.com/antonmedv/fx

```
$ echo '[1,2,3]' | fx "this.map(x => x * 2)"
[2, 4, 6]
```

[image]

https://github.com/antonmedv/fx